# Interface for Vector and Matrix classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, matrix

I have a generic `Vector<T>` class and a generic `Matrix<T>` class and I was wondering if it would be a good idea to have both classes implement an interface.

Basically, I'm implementing two algorithms: AlgorithmA and AlgorithmB, both of which perform very similar operations (reset, average...etc) but with different algorithms and act on different structures: 
`AlgorithmA` uses `Vector<double>` while `AlgorithmB` uses `Matrix<Complex>`.

The design I have so far:

```
abstract class AlgorithmArray
{
   // Operator overloading
}

class AlgorithmAArray : AlgorithmArray
{
    private Vector<double> _vector;

    // Overrides
}

class  AlgorithmBArray : AlgorithmArray
{
     private Matrix<Complex> _matrix;

     // Overrides
}
```

I would prefer to have `AlgorithmAArray` derive from `Vector<T>` and also implement an interface '`IAlgorithmArray`' (instead of the abstract class). Anyway, these algorithms are then used to simulate transmission/receiving between two locations:

```
public class CommunicationParameters
{
         private AlgorithmArray _transmission;
         private AlgorithmArray _receiving;

         public void Compute()
        {
            if(_transmission != null)
                 _transmission.Compute();

            if(_receiving != null)         
                 _receiving.Compute()

        }
}
```

Are there better ways to approach my problem ?

Note: The base class `AlgorithmArray` duplicates many of the operator/cloning...etc methods and I feel this could be avoided, perhaps using generics ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making two Algorithm classes that can take any data structure as a parameter and do their thing.  I don't see a need for all this OOP inheritance, it just adds complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces would allow routines which only read or only write vectors/matrices to accept vectors/matrices of a subtype or supertype of the expected vector/matrix type.  I'm not sure that would generally be useful with matrices, but it could be handy with some applications of vectors.

Another advantage of interfaces over classes, which might be more applicable to your situation, would be that they could allow smooth interoperation between mutable, immutable, and copy-on-write objects (the latter requiring an extra level of indirection).  This could be useful if you have lots of vectors or matrices which are going to be copies of one another, but a few of them will end up getting modified.  Methods `AsImmutable`, `AsNewMutable`, and `AsPossiblyExistingMutable` can be useful for that.  The first method (if invoked on a mutable object) will either create a new immutable object whose contents match those of its subject at the time of the call, or (if invoked on an immutable) object, simply return its subject.  The second will create a new mutable object regardless of whether the existing object is mutable or immutable.  The third method will return its subject if mutable, or else create a new mutable object; it should generally only be used in cases where the holder of an object would know that, if the object is mutable, it holds the only reference.

For example, if I have a private field `_thing` of type `IReadableVector<Foo>`, my setter could set it to `value.AsImmutable()` and my getter could return `_thing.AsImmutable()`.  My mutating method would set `_thing = _thing.AsPossiblyExistingMutable()` before calling mutating methods on it.  If I haven't tried to mutate `_thing` since I received it, it would be an immutable object (to which other objects might also hold references).  The first time I mutate it, it would be copied to a new mutable object.  Subsequent mutations, however, could keep using the same mutable object, since it would never get exposed to any outside code.

PS--There are arguments both for and against having `IImmutableVector<T>` and `IImmutableMatrix<T>` as interfaces, versus only having `ImmutableVector<T>` and `ImmutableMatrix<T>` classes.  On the one hand, if they're interfaces, it's possible to have useful implementations which don't need to actually store all the elements.  For example, one could have a classes like `AllMatchingVector<T>` which inherits `IImmutableVector<T>` but just contains one `T` and a number indicating its length; its indexed getter would simply return that element regardless of the specified index, or `DiagonalMatrix<T>` which simply holds an `IImmutableVector<T>` for the contents of its diagonal, and a `T` which would be returned everywhere else; especially for large vectors/matrices, such classes could save memory.  On the other hand, there would be no way of ensuring that nobody implemented one of those interfaces with a class which was not, in fact, immutable.  My personal feeling is that it's fine to use interfaces for that.  After all, few people complain that `SortedDictionary<T>` will fail if a class implements `IComparable<T>` in a fashion that doesn't yield an immutable sorting relation.  Nonetheless, a lot of people disagree with such a concept.